# Trying to use SQL to pull flat data into an array-like answer

Tags: sql

I am trying to use SQL to pull flat data into an array-like answer, and need some help.

The flat data is formatted as:

```
timestamp, unique_id, value
```

... over and over again on each row down the table I call "temperature_values". When you look at the table, it has lots of rows with a unique_id of "temp_low" and lots of rows with a unique_id of "temp_high". For each timestamp, there is a single row with the "temp_low" unique_id and a single row with the "temp_high" unique_id values. Of course, the timestamp field is the same on each of these rows.

So if I want to query just the "temp_low" or the "temp_high", it's very easy.

But what I'd like to do is have a single SQL statement that returns:

```
timestamp, temp_low, temp_high
```

... having the timestamp as unique on each result row, so that it's easy to graph the high and slow temperatures for each timestamp. I've tried some INNER JOINs into the same table, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to solve this.

Any clues?

TIA - Dave

Answer (score 1):

A self join is a good solution.  If temp low and temp high are the only possible unique ids and if the low is truly always less than or equal to the high, you could also do:

```
SELECT timestamp, min(value) as temp_low, max(value) as temp_high
FROM table_name
GROUP BY timestamp
```

Edit: by joining the table to itself the following will work (assuming every timestamp has exactly one high row and one low row)

```
SELECT low.timestamp,
    low.value temp_low,
    high.value temp_high
FROM table_name low
JOIN table_name high
ON low.timestamp = high.timestamp
WHERE low.unique_id = 'temp_low'
    AND high.unique_id = 'temp_high'
```

Or assuming every timestamp has at most one high row and one low row but not necessarily both:

```
SELECT coalesce(low.timestamp, high.timestamp) timestamp,
    low.value temp_low,
    high.value temp_high
FROM table_name low
FULL OUTER JOIN table_name high
ON low.timestamp = high.timestamp
WHERE (low.unique_id = 'temp_low' OR low.timestamp is null)
    AND (high.unique_id = 'temp_high' OR high.timestamp is null)
```

Comment: Love your first solution - its brilliant for this particular problem. And yes, the high and low values are just that, except that the high and low could be the same for a certain timeframe. Thanks!

Comment: Yes thanks for that fix, sorry I wrote from my phone.. if this is the correct answer it should be marked I think.

Answer (score 0):

This works from joining between two sub-queries (q1 and q2), and allows you to ignore any ID's that aren't high or low:

```
SELECT q1.timestamp AS Time, High, Low FROM 
(SELECT timestamp, value AS High FROM temps
WHERE ID = 'temp_high') q1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT timestamp, value AS Low From temps
WHERE ID = 'temp_low') q2 ON q1.Date = q2.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) may be a good reference for JOINs.  Assuming the values are separated into separated tables and the time stamps match you could join them on the time-stamp.

```
SELECT temp_low_table.timestamp AS timestamp, temp_low_table.temp_low AS temp_low, temp_high_table.temp_high AS temp_high
FROM temp_low_table
INNER JOIN temp_high_table
ON temp_low_table.timestamp=temp_high_table.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution that doesn't involve joins is to use a `group by` + an aggregate function (like `min` or `max`) with a `case` statement:

```
select timestamp,
       max(case when unique_id = 'temp_low' then value end) as temp_low,
       max(case when unique_id = 'temp_high' then value end) as temp_high
  from temperature_values
 group by timestamp
```